# TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined on guildCreate event

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a problem regarding the definition of `guild.id`. I am trying to create an event which will create a config for a server when the bot enters it.

`event.handler.js`:

```js
const { readdirSync } = require("fs")
const ascii = require("ascii-table")
const chalk = require("chalk")
const {Constants: {Events}} = require("discord.js")


const serverEvents = Object.values(Events)

module.exports = (client) => {
    const events = readdirSync(__dirname + "/../events").filter((file) =>
    file.endsWith(".event.js"),
  )  
    for (const file of events) {
        const event = require(__dirname + `/../events/${file}`)
        if(!event.run) {
            console.log(chalk.redBright.bold(`event o nazwie '${file}' nie wykrywa funkcji run()! sprawdz dany plik!`));
            process.exit(1)
        }else if(typeof event.run !== 'function'){
            console.log(chalk.redBright.bold(`event o nazwie '${file}' nie wykrywa funkcji run()! sprawdz dany plik!`));
            process.exit(1)
        }
        if (serverEvents.includes(event.name)){
            client.on(event.name, event.run)  
        }else {
            console.log(chalk.redBright.bold(`event o nazwie '${file}' ma nie poprawną nazwe eventu!`));
            process.exit(1)
        }
    }
    
}
```

`onJoinBotGuild.event.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "guildCreate",
 
    async run(msg) {
        const { guild, client } = msg
        const { settings } = client
        // Save channel id to config
        if (!settings.get(guild.id)) {
          settings.set(guild.id, { clocks:[], prefix:[] })
        }
        
        client.saveConfig(guild.id)
    
    }
}
```

`index.js`:

```js
const { Client } = require("discord.js")
const chalk = require("chalk")

const { token } = require("./config/config.js")

const client = new Client()

const commandHandler = require("./handlers/command.handler")
const settingsHandler = require("./handlers/settings.handler")
const eventHandler = require("./handlers/event.handler.js")

const log = console.log
const {guild} = client
// Initialize Comamnd Manager
commandHandler(client)
// Initialize Settings Manager
settingsHandler(client)

eventHandler(client)

client.on("ready", () => {
  log(chalk.green(`Zalogowałeś się jako... -> `+chalk.red.bold( ` ${client.user.tag}!`)));
  

  client.user.setPresence({ activity: { name: '*Jeśli potrzebujesz pomoocy użyj ?help*',type:'WATCHING' }, status: 'dnd' })


  
  
  
  // Initialize interval for each guild
  client.settings.forEach((config, guildId) => {

    const { guilds } = client


    // Check if guild exist
    if (guilds.cache.has(guildId)) {
      const guild = guilds.cache.get(guildId)
      // Check if available
      if (guild.available) {
        // console.log("available")

        // Set Interval for each channel
        const clockChannels = config.clocks
        setInterval(() => {
          const time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString().slice(0, 5)
          const channelName = ` ${time}`

          clockChannels.forEach((channelId, index) => {
            // Check if channel exists
            if (guild.channels.cache.has(channelId)) {
              // log("channel exist")
              const channelToUpdate = guild.channels.cache.get(channelId)
              channelToUpdate.setName(channelName)
            } else {
              // log("not exist")
              // Remove Id from config
              // that does not exist?
              clockChannels.splice(index, 1)
              client.saveConfig(guildId)
            }
          })
        }, 1000)
      }
    }
    client.saveConfig(guildId)
  })
})

// Connect with Discord
client.login(token)

// Error handler - omit crashed
client.on("debug", () => {})
client.on("warn", () => {})
client.on("error", () => {})
```

`settings.handler.js`:

```js
const { Collection } = require("discord.js")
const { readdirSync, readFileSync, writeFileSync } = require("fs")
const yaml = require("js-yaml")
 
// Load server settings
const serverConfigPath = "/config/servers"
 
module.exports = (client) => {
  // Settings Collection
  client.settings = new Collection()
 
  const settingsFiles = readdirSync(
    __dirname + `/..${serverConfigPath}`,
  ).filter((file) => file.endsWith(".yaml"))
 
  try {
    for (const file of settingsFiles) {
      const settingsFile = readFileSync(
        __dirname + `/..${serverConfigPath}/${file}`,
        "utf8",
      )
 
      const data = yaml.load(settingsFile)
      const guildId = file.split(".")[0]
 
      // Set server settings
      client.settings.set(guildId, data)
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
 
  client.saveConfig = (guildId) => {
    if (client.settings.has(guildId)) {
      const config = client.settings.get(guildId)
 
      try {
        const yamlStr = yaml.dump(config)
 
        writeFileSync(
          __dirname + `/..${serverConfigPath}/${guildId}.yaml`,
          yamlStr,
          "utf8",
        )
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The error that occurs looks like this:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at Client.run (E:\Mega\GalusSecurtity\GalusSecurity\src\events\onJoinBotGuild.event.js:7:35)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Object.module.exports [as GUILD_CREATE] (E:\Mega\GalusSecurtity\GalusSecurity\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\GUILD_CREATE.js:33:14)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (E:\Mega\GalusSecurtity\GalusSecurity\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (E:\Mega\GalusSecurtity\GalusSecurity\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)       
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (E:\Mega\GalusSecurtity\GalusSecurity\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)      
    at WebSocket.onMessage (E:\Mega\GalusSecurtity\GalusSecurity\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (E:\Mega\GalusSecurtity\GalusSecurity\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:825:20)
    at Receiver.emit (events.js:315:20)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:15832) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:15832) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Where do you call the `run()` method? And please, make sure you post your code directly here next time.

Comment: okey i add index and event handler where i called the `run()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you try to get the message on a [`guildCreate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildCreate) event that is emitted whenever the bot joins a guild. The `guildCreate` takes one parameter, the guild created. This `guild` has a [`client`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Guild?scrollTo=client) property so you can use that in your handler.

So the error is that when you destructure `const { guild, client } = msg`, `guild` will be undefined as there is no `guild` property on `guild`, only `client`. :)

Try to update your `onJoinBotGuild.event.js` file like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'guildCreate',
  async run(guild) {
    const { client } = guild;
    const { settings } = client;

    // Save channel id to config
    if (!settings.get(guild.id)) {
      settings.set(guild.id, { clocks: [], prefix: [] });
    }

    client.saveConfig(guild.id);
  },
};
```